# Finding the rows which has a unique column values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I have a dataframe of the above structure. I want to get the columns which has a column sum of 1. The columns should be combined together if they have 1's for the same row. So if we see the above example we should get column `[3],[4,5],[6],[7,8,9]` as output. I tried doing`df.columns[df.sum(axis=0) == 1]` but instead of getting them in group(when they have same row's) I am getting them as individual...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `sub_df` where column sums are 1:

```
sub_df = df.loc[:, df.sum()==1]

sub_df
Out[105]: 
   2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
5  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

And then group those columns by the position of 1's (position of the max):

```
sub_df.groupby(sub_df.idxmax(), axis = 1).groups
Out[107]: {0: [5], 3: [2], 4: [6, 7, 8], 5: [3, 4]}
```

The result is a dictionary. You can access the values by `dict.values()`:

```
d = sub_df.groupby(sub_df.idxmax(), axis = 1).groups
d.values()
Out[110]: dict_values([[5], [2], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4]])
```

The column names in my example were zero-based numbers. You can  iterate over the dictionary to add 1 to those values.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
s = df.loc[:, df.sum(axis=0) == 1].idxmax(axis=0)

[[int(j) for j in i] for i in s.groupby(s).groups.values()]
```

Looks like:

```
[[5], [2], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4]]
```

---

EDIT:

This is essentially the same exact answer as ayhan.  I posted maybe 2 seconds after he/she did.  I'm leaving mine here because I handled converting long int to int.  Please choose his/her answer over mine.